# Find the biggest area of an isosceles triangle in an unit circle

Tags: calculus, geometry

An isosceles triangle is inscribed in the unit circle. Determine the largest area of ​​the triangle can assume.

**My solution attempt:**

An isosceles triangle has two sides of equal size, and the sides will be at some point on the circumference of the unit circle during suggestion the $x$-axis. The height will be $1 + h \le 2$ and width $b + 1 \le 2$

Another way would be to make the vectors of the three points that will be on the periphery (assuming that it can provide the largest area on the periphery)

**I really do not know how to solve it.**

Comment: Try to show that the condition $\Rightarrow $ the triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The triangle is $\Delta ABC$: $AB=AC=b$ and $BC=a$.

Also $\angle A=2x \rightarrow \angle B=\frac{\pi - 2x}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$, so:

$$S(ABC)=\frac{b^2\sin 2x}{2}$$

And by sine rule:

$$\frac{b}{\sin \angle B}=2\cdot 1 \rightarrow b=2\cdot \cos x$$

and then:

$$S(ABC)=2\cdot \cos^2x\cdot\sin 2x=(1+\cos 2x)\cdot \sin 2x$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

equilateral triangle has maximum area

side would be $\sqrt{3}$ by using trigonometry

area is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}a^2$$=$$\frac{3\sqrt 3}{4}$

Comment: Without arguments this isn't worth anything.

Comment: for what ?clerify what you are asking.

Comment: You are making an assertion of the answer rather than determining it. To be useful, you would show how you know that the equilateral triangle is the maximum area.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed a central angle within the circle A to create an additional isosceles triangle and find the base N, as well as find the total height.

Because this is a unit circle, the radius is 1.

With the central angle A, we create the isosceles triangle with base N and with base angles X and with height K.

Drawing a perpendicular bisector down from the vertex of A creates two right triangles; each has height K, base angle X, upper angle (for lack of a better term) a/2, and hypotenuse of 1 (because the radius is 1). With this, we can create some functions/equations based on the variables:

X = 90 - (A/2)

sin(x) = K

cos(x) = n/2

2cos(x) = n

The total height of the isosceles triangle in question (the one with the largest area) is given by K+1.

The base of the isosceles triangle with base angle X is given by N (as is the largest possible isosceles triangle).

The area of a triangle is given by ((base*height)/2).

Therefore, we can perform substitutions, and get that

(2cos(x)(sin(x) + 1))/2 = Area.

More simply, cos(x)(sin(x) + 1) = Area.

However, we established these relations based on an assumed central angle; therefore, we need to substitute.

cos(90 - (a/2))(sin(90 - (a/2)) + 1) = Area.

Proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

First note that the two angles in the figure below must be equal (the two triangles in the lower part of the picture are congruent by side-angle-side). Denote their common value by $\theta$.

The area of the triangle is then $A(\theta) = \frac{\sin2\theta}{2}+\sin\theta$, where  $0<\theta<\pi$.

Now find the maximum of $A$ on its domain.

[image]